# Excel #VALUE error with COUNTIF inside LET function when using FILTER

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, unique, countif

I am trying to write a formula using `LET`, `FILTER`, `COUNTIF` and dynamic ranges to count occurrences of unique values in a table column.

I have an excel table `tbl` with one column `df_col` like this:

| df_col |
| --- |
| a |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| c |
| c |

I wrote the following excel function that outputs the unique values alongside the count in the table.

```
=LET(
  col_all; tbl[df_col];
  col_uniq; UNIQUE(col_all);
  col_count; COUNTIF(col_all; col_uniq);
  HSTACK(col_uniq; col_count)
)
```

The result I get is what I have expected

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2 |
| b | 1 |
| c | 3 |

Next I wanted to add some `FILTER` on the column to do this for a subset of the data.

```
=LET(
  col_filtered; FILTER(tbl[df_col]; tbl[df_col]<="b");
  col_uniq; UNIQUE(col_filtered);
  col_count; COUNTIF(col_filtered; col_uniq);
  HSTACK(col_uniq; col_count);
)
```

The result throw errors. Seems the `COUNTIF` function is not working on the retrieved list.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| a | #VALUE |
| b | #VALUE |
| #N/A | #VALUE |

Running the formula evaluation shows an error in the `COUNTIF` part. Nevertheless doing these step-by-step in excel without the `LET` function works fine.

What's the issue?

Comment: The problem could be simplified to why this code is not working.
=LET(
  data; {"a";"a";"b";"c";"c";"c"};
  data_unique; UNIQUE(data);
  COUNTIF(data; data_unique)
)

Comment: Suggest you look for the `GROUPBY()` function. It does all you want in this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNTIF` function requires a range of cells.

In your first example the reference to the table is converted as a range of cells.

In the second one, and in the comments the passed parameters are arrays, which is not accepted by the function. This results in a #VALUE error

Info: [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)

Comment: thanks, that explains why its not working. Is there any alternative function that could count occurrences in an array directly?

Comment: You were a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for the `COUNTIF` reference restriction that works for my case

```
=LET(
  col_all; FILTER(tbl[df_col]; tbl[df_col]<="b");
  col_uniq; UNIQUE(col_all);
  col_count; BYROW(col_uniq; LAMBDA(x; SUM(--(col_all=x))));
  res;HSTACK(col_uniq; col_count);
  res
)
```